# Слитно или через дефис? (2)

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис, сложные-слова

Как пишутся слова «психо(-)разбор» и «психо(-)обзор»?

Answer (score 2):

Слова *психоразбор* и *психообзор* (несмотря на их отсутствие в словарях) надо писать слитно.

В орфографическом словаре:
[**психо...**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE) — первая часть сложных слов, пишется слитно.
В толковом словаре:
психоневрология, психопатология, психотерапевт, психофизиология; психоанализ.

Разъятие атомного ядра, кибернетика, полеты в космос, **психоанализ**, генетика, абстрактное искусство, стиль Корбюзье и прочее и прочее ― почти ничего не было зачато в Америке, но почти все получило дальнейшее развитие именно там. [Виктор Розов. Удивление перед жизнью (1960-2000)]

*Ангела Кумуса привезли на **психоосвидетельствование** только в два часа дня* (Нина Васина. Женщина-апельсин).